# Netlify error when uploading a file: Origin returned error code

Tags: html, upload, hosting, web-hosting, netlify

[this is the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPJBH.png), which just says "*Origin returned error code*".

[the structure of my website folder is like this, and the index.html file is inside the "Home page" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alp1h.png)

Comment: Is there any more detail printed in the browser console? And can you provide steps in words on how to reproduce the issue- if possible? (see the instructions on how to provide a [mre])

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.